# How do angles of two linked rotatable rods change in dependence on their corresponding lengths (of their ratio $\frac{r_1}{r_2}$)?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, classical-mechanics

Suppose a system of four rods with known dimensions $r_1, r_2, a, l$ is given (see picture).

[image: System of four roads with rotatable linkages]

The black rod between the points $A_1$ and $A_2$ is fixed in space, whereas the linkages at points $A_1, A_2, B_1, B_2$ can rotate.
How can the change of the fist angle $\alpha_1$ be described in terms of $\alpha_2$? Is it possible to set up an ordinary differential equation? How would a plot of $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$ look like? I have animated the movement in GeoGebra, but I'm still interested in the maths behind this:

[image: Animation in GeoGebra]

This is particularly interesting in regards of a mechanism I am currently designing, I'd be thankful for any advice!

Comment: Reminds me of [this old question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/780997/11619). I don't think you need any [tag:classical-mechanics] here. Just geometry and/or trigonometry. Of course, if you also need to work out the forces and torques on the hinges. Anyway, this is different from that one. Not the least because some choices of $\alpha_1$ may make the distance between $A_2$ and $B_1$ either $>a+r_2$ or $<|a-r_2|$, when triangle inequality would be violated.

Comment: But this is also similar to the other question in the sense that given $A_1,A_2,B_1$ there are to possible points $B_2$. They are mirror images of each other with respect to the line $A_2B_1$. Of course, your machine may constrain the motion in such a way that the other solution is out of the question.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen This indeed looks very similar! In my case $r_1 + r_2 < l$ the two rods do not cross and the area enclosed by points $A_1, A_2, B_2, B_1$ is always convex. Also the radii $r_1, r_2$ are different...

Comment: Write the equations of the x,y projections of a parallel and perpendicular of a into l and than use Pythagorean relation.

Comment: Do you follow my explanation? It is not differential equation. It is a polynomial of trigonometric function.

Comment: @Moti yes! The problem has been solved in the meantime, and as you mentioned it turned out to be a rater simple equation consisting of trigonometric functions using pythagoras. Solving for the desired angle is a bit harder, but can be done numerically. Thanks!

Comment: I can confirm that when I made the comment I reached exactly the same result.

Answer (score 1):

I reached out to my old Physics teacher and he kindly set up relationships using Pythagoras and simple trigonometry from which the following equation arises:
$$r_1^2+r_2^2 - 2 r_1r_2\cos(\alpha_1-\alpha_2)-2l(r_1 \cos(\alpha_1)+r_2 \cos(\alpha_2)) = a^2$$
Solving for $\alpha_1$ analytically turned out to be rather complicated though...